# How to improve XVFB display quality

Tags: xvfb, x11vnc

I am currently running chrome on AWS Linux servers with this [Puppeteer and XVFB setup](https://github.com/nsourov/Puppeteer-with-xvfb).
I also built a little chrome extension that handles the recording with *MediaRecorder* and *chrome.tabCapture*.

It's basically meant to spin up chrome on the server and record a video of a specific page. To get a virtual display on the server, I've had to use XVFB.
I just hit a little block on video quality. It doesn't get as clear enough even after increasing the bitrate as high as 11mbit/s. Screen resolution is 1920x1080. I'd appreciate some pointers/tips on how to improve the quality from the XVFB side.

PS: The typical server I'm running this on has 4 vCPUs and 16gb memory.

Comment: XVFB doesn't and cannot degrade video quality, it outputs everything as is. Look into your VNC capture/encoding setup.

Comment: Thanks @ArtemS.Tashkinov! But we don't use VNC - we don't need to remotely control the screen, we just need to record the browser and upload the WebM format to AWS S3